# Why JPA Buddy complains about @Data annotation over JPA Entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, lombok, jpa-buddy

I discovered JPA Buddy plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. In all my projects i love to use Lombok. It saves a lot of space in my entity classes. However, i just noticed, that JPA Buddy highliths it and suggest to replace.

E.g.:
[image: inspection]

As a result, the @Data annotation is replaced with:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
```

- the hashCode and equals implementations were added:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) {
            return false;
        }
        Project project = (Project) o;
        return id != null && Objects.equals(id, project.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
```

I clearly see the desription:
Using @Data for JPA entities is not recommended. It can cause severe performance and memory consumption issues

But can somebody provide some real world example? From my perspective, @Data includes everything i need (equals/hashcode) as well. And i didn't notice any performance issues in my projects.

Comment: (mini rant) Hibernate/JPA is a complicated technology, it's important that one knows its caveats before using it. I often see teams using hibernate (and spring-jpa) with little idea of how it works and this causes all kinds of unexpected errors (and workaround hacks, which makes the code hard to read). I would *strongly* suggest you to get a book that explains the basics (maybe `Java Persistence with Hibernate`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JPA Buddy follows best practices, and @Data for JPA entities is an antipattern...
You can read more here (with some real-world examples): https://www.jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/.

In short:

1. According to the JPA specification, all entity classes are required to have a public or protected no-argument constructor. @Data includes only @AllArgsConstructor and not @NoArgsConstructor
2. You can easily load attributes that are marked as Lazy due to the default @ToString method implementation provided by Lombok – which can significantly reduce the performance of your app.
3. Finally, @EqualsAndHashCode implementation can break HashSets (and HashMaps) behavior under certain conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this [blog post](https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/), it explains what could go wrong with Lombok's generated equals() and hashCode() inside JPA entity classes and why it should be avoided

Comment: Unfortunately that blog is unreadable. It just bombards you with popups.